# ¿Cómo puedo leer un archivo de excel (xlsx) con contraseña en R?

Tags: r, rstudio

Estoy tratando de importar un archivo xlsx con contraseña (tengo la contraseña) en R. Gracias!

Comment: Bienvenido/a Marely a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando así, tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Answer (score 2):

Puedes usar el paquete [`xlsx`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/xlsx/versions/0.6.1) que cuenta con el parámetro `password`:

```
df <- xlsx::read.xlsx("tu_archivo.xlsx", 
                       sheetIndex = 1,
                       password = "tu contraseña")
```